# How do I delete/ignore some rows while parsing data from Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, xlrd

Recently I am trying to parse data from Excel sheet using Python and I successfully parsed it but I don't need some rows from that Excel sheet. So how do I do it(may be using looping)? Here the code which I wrote to parse the Excel sheet:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel.xlsx")

sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
firstcol = sheet.col_values(0)
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in 
        range(sheet.nrows)]

ele=''
year=[]

for j in range(len(data)):
    if j==1:
        year=data[j]
    if j>2:
        ele=data[j][0]

        for i in range(1, len(data[j])):
            if ele != "":
                if data[j][i] != "":
                    if year[i] !="":
                        print([ele, data[j][i], year[i]])
```

With that all rows are parsing in list format which I want, but I don't want some rows**( Like Total age, Total IDs, Total Result)** from Excel file, So how can I implement it in the same code or suggest some other effective way(may be pandas) to reduce code or any powerful way. The Excel file to which I'm referring:
[Click to see Excel.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjWA5.jpg)

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: The problem is that any external access to Excel almost certainly can't tell a detail row from a total row, because it only looks at the values not the formulas. If all your total rows start with 'Total', can't you just ignore those in your loop? Otherwise, can you change the Excel so that there's some obvious marker of that sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this much more simply.  You have some list of rows to exclude:

```
rows_to_exclude = ['Total age', 'Total IDS', 'Total Result']
```

You can read in the dataframe using [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) without xlrd (no need to specify the sheet index if it's the first sheet, which is read by default).  Then you can drop the rows with missing values, and drop all rows whose index is in your list of excluded row labels:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Excel.xlsx')
df = df.dropna().drop(rows_to_exclude)
```

Comment: Here I import the pandas but not useful in this code so, can you please tell me how it do with core python according to this code

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're saying - do you want to do it without pandas?  Because in your question you ask for "some effective way (maybe pandas)" and your question is tagged "pandas".